# preciso calcular a frequencia da ocorrencia de uma varivavel

Tags: r

Tenho dois vetores, um com 387 códigos e outro com 3 mil ocorrências de um ou mais desses 387 códigos. Preciso saber quantas vezes cada um desses 387 códigos ocorreu nesse vetor das 3 mil ocorrências. Já fiz com loops "for" e deu certo, mas o tempo de execução é gigantesco. Tentei usar o comando "table" mas não deu certo. Vi uma sugestão do daniel mas a mesma cria um data-frame com duas variáveis (ok) mas com o mesmo número de linhas, o que não é o meu caso.

Comment: O que não deu certo no comando `table`?  Do mais, disponibilize seu conjunto de dados, ou uma parte dele (comando `dput`) para que seu problema possa ser reproduzido.

Comment: Peço desculpas, Rafael, estava usando o comando "table" inadequadamente, agora deu certo.
Grato pela mensagem,